# Creating a lightweight 1 degree x 1 degree mesh with GeoJSON?

Tags: openlayers, geojson, vector-grid

I have produced via QGIS a 1°x1° mesh polygon and exported that in GeoJSON format. However, the file is 11-15 MB large. That is really too heavy to be used in Web applications, such as OpenLayers (which I intend to do).

The format looks like this:

```
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-179,90],[-179,89],[-180,89],[-180,90],[-179,90]]]},"properties":{"left":-180,"top":90,"right":-179,"bottom":89}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-180,89],[-179,89],[-179,88],[-180,88],[-180,89]]]},"properties":{"left":-180,"top":89,"right":-179,"bottom":88}},
```

I wonder if there isn't a way of producing a lighter version of such a grid. Perhaps even some on-the-fly, dynamically generated layer in OpenLayers?

My aim is to lay this mesh on a global map; the user can click on a square, which sends a request to a server with the ID of the square; the server responds with a pre-calculated value for that square-ID.

Comment: Would it be easier to adjust the server so that it takes a lat/lon point as input and then returns the correct response? (Internally it might need to transform from lat/lon to your grid, but that feels like something internal that shouldn't be exposed).

Comment: Another spitball is to look at topojson.

Comment: I'd want the user to see the rectangles, as this shows the extent of the research area. Topojson comes down to even 45MB. Thanks!

Comment: how did you create the grid?

Comment: @iant: QGIS: Processing Toolbox -> Vector creation tools -> Create grid.